# Dataflow-Apache beam insert into ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow, clickhouse

I have ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree(table1), I have built 3 MVs on this also of the same type. I am trying to insert streaming data(using dataflow(beam)) into table1. It used to work as normal ReplacingMergeTree when I change to replicated I get the error below. what is the problem ?

> 2020-02-24 17:07:37.365 ISTError message from worker: ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 306, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 306, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Stack size too large. Stack address: 0x7feae15fe000, frame address: 0x7feae19fe210, stack size: 4197872, maximum stack size: 8392704 (version 19.17.4.11 (official build)) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:58) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.finishBundle(ClickHouseIO.java:403) Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Code: 306, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Stack size too large. Stack address: 0x7feae15fe000, frame address: 0x7feae19fe210, stack size: 4197872, maximum stack size: 8392704 (version 19.17.4.11 (official build)) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:53) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.finishBundle(ClickHouseIO.java:403) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.AutoValue_ClickHouseIO_WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.finishBundle(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:423) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:56) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1350) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:152) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1073) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 306, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 306, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Stack size too large. Stack address: 0x7fe5abdfc000, frame address: 0x7fe5ac1fc210, stack size: 4197872, maximum stack size: 8392704 (version 19.17.4.11 (official build)) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:58) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.finishBundle(ClickHouseIO.java:403) Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Code: 306, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Stack size too large. Stack address: 0x7fe5abdfc000, frame address: 0x7fe5ac1fc210, stack size: 4197872, maximum stack size: 8392704 (version 19.17.4.11 (official build)) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:53) ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106) ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764) ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.finishBundle(ClickHouseIO.java:403) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.AutoValue_ClickHouseIO_WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.finishBundle(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:423) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:56) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1350) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:152) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1073) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse and put CH server log

Comment: Could you provide the schema of ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree-table and cluster-config?